# How to parse Byte Order Mark UTF-8 text file in objective C ios

Tags: ios, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have sent a text file as an attachment from from whatsapp and then when opened the sent file in iPhone app I am seeing `=EF=BB=BF` in start which means it is BOM utf-8 file. My question is why '`=`' character is coming after every code instead of `0x`?

Also all emoji are coming in this style `=F0=9F=98=9D`, how can I convert this into simple text in objective C? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). This encoding scheme escapes non-printable ASCII or 8-bit characters as `=xx` where `xx` is the hex value of the byte. Quoted-printable is mainly used in email transmission. See the question [Objective-C decode quoted printable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298798/objective-c-decode-quoted-printable-text) for tips on decoding.